# Get only IATA code with geocoding

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

How can I have just the IATA codes with Google Maps? I just found out how to get the address and city, but I need to grab just the IATA code, like NYC or JFK etc. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [Global Airport Database](http://www.partow.net/miscellaneous/airportdatabase/). It has GPS coordinates.

Comment: I'm looking to grab it from google maps, I dont want to download anything.

Answer (score 6):

You can try use this service:

GET Request Params: http://iatageo.com/getCode/{lat}/{lng}

GET Request Example: http://iatageo.com/getCode/-15.4343434/-47.323232

This will return a JSON, for example:

```js
{
  "code": "BSB",
  "distance_meters": "127763.232556459"
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

The Google geocoder will not return the IATA code if you reverse geocode a location. It does return a location if you give it an IATA code.

You can geocode KJFK at https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple (it places a marker at 40.64384360,-73.78230350).

If you reverse-geocode that location with https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse you get lots of data but neither three-letter nor four-letter code are included. (The formatted address includes "JFK" but that can't be guaranteed: you would need it as an identifiable data item)

If you want to find an IATA code for a particular location, you will need to use another resource.

Comment: thanks Andrew . Now i giving City name with IATA code . Results are acceptable now