# How to get Latitude & Longitude from Airport code?

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps-api-3

How to get Latitude & Longitude from Airport code?
I want to plot nearest airport and i have just IATA code but dont want to use data base or pre stored lat long.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try google. You'll have much a much better chance of finding an answer there.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872154/get-only-iata-code-with-geocoding

Comment: Try http://openflights.org/data.html or http://ourairports.com/data/ or http://www.partow.net/miscellaneous/airportdatabase/ for the source data.

Answer (score 1):

WebServiceX has methods to look up an airport's information based on its code.

http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=20&CATID=7